# What's the Mac OS X way to execute this command

Tags: macos, ubuntu, sed, terminal

I am trying to execute this command:

```
find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/A/B/g" {} \;
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
find: -readable: unknown primary or operator
```

I am trying to find and replace extensively, anything with the name 'A' to 'B', this will apply to file names and text inside of files.

What's the best way for me to execute this on Mac terminal?

Comment: while you're at your Terminal, use `man find` to read the manual page for the command. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The BSD version of `find` doesn't have the `-readable` or `-writable` primaries, but you can fake them using the `test` command:

```
find ./ -type f -exec test -r {} -a -w {} \; -exec sed -i "" "s/A/B/g" {} \;
```

There's a possible problem here in that `test`'s syntax can be ambiguous with more than three arguments, so a compound test expression like this might be misparsed. I don't think this can be a problem with paths that begin with `./`, but if you're worried about it you can use two separate tests:

```
find ./ -type f -exec test -r {} \; -exec -w {} \; -exec sed -i "" "s/A/B/g" {} \;
```

Also, note that I added a null argument to `sed` after `-i`. This is another BSD-vs-GNU thing. The BSD version of `sed` requires an argument (the extension to use for a backup) to the `-i` option, so in order to avoid making a backup you have to explicitly supply a blank. The GNU version, on the other hand, would be confused by `sed -i .bak` because it requires the argument to `-i` be directly attached to it (`sed -i.bak`). Wheee.

Comment: I tried it and I got "sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence"

Comment: @GabrielBalza I think that means it's trying to operate on a non-text file, and running into file contents that aren't valid UTF-8 (or whatever your current locale says it should be). You can add `-exec echo {} \;` *before* the `-exec sed` section to make it print filenames before editing them, and see which one's causing trouble.